# Change Background on DragEnter

Tags: wpf

I want to change the background of a framework element when the DragEnter event is fired and revert its background when the DragLeave event is fired. Additionally, I want this applied in a style.

Heres what I have currently:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.DragEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="DragHoverStoryboard">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="??????????"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                     Duration="0:0:0"
                                     To="{DynamicResource HoverBrush}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.DragLeave">
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="DragHoverStoryboard" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Drop">
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="DragHoverStoryboard" />
        </EventTrigger>
```

The problem here is that I can't apply target by a name because this style can be applied to any FrameworkElement. How do I apply the target to the element that the Style is attached to?

Comment: Doesn't it use the current object this style is applied to if the `TargetName` is left blank?

Answer (score 2):

Storyboard.Target is not the problem, just leave it out. However, you need to change the rest of the animation. To animate a color, use a ColorAnimation instead of a DoubleAnimation. Also, the property "Background" does not contain a color but a brush, so animate the property "Background.Color" instead. Here is a working example:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.DragEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="DragHoverStoryboard">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0" To="Green" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.DragLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0" To="Red" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```